# Не отображается меню

Tags: menu, android, java

Здравствуйте!

Не могу понять, почему не отображается меню на устройствах, где нет кнопки Меню, т.е. выше api10. Там, где есть кнопка, - все Ок.

Делаю так:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {  
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);  
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);}

Menu__main:  
    <item   
        android:id="@+id/action_ID_device"   
        android:title="@string/action_ID_device"   
        android:orderInCategory="100"   
        app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотря какая у вас тема в приложении. Если вы используете библиотеку `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3` , то должны использовать **`Theme.AppCompat`**

```
 <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

А так же в menu `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

В других случаях у вас menu должны выглядеть так:

```
<item   
    android:id="@+id/action_ID_device"   
    android:title="@string/action_ID_device"   
    android:orderInCategory="100"   
    android:showAsAction="always" />
```

Comment: Да, проблема была именно в этом. 
Только я установил 
     android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.CompactMenu"
и все заработало.
Благодарю за ответ.